# Maximum call stack size exceeded. I'm using nextjs

Tags: typescript, next.js13

I'm using nextjs 13.4 to make like button functioning. I got this error:

> Error: Maximum call stack size exceeded

I want the button to be increment when user like the button.

I'm a junior developer and I need your help please. Thanks for your help

```
"use client"
import { formatDateString } from "@/lib/utils";
import Image from "next/image";
import Link from "next/link";
import { useEffect, useState } from "react";
import DeleteBuzzWeft from "../forms/DeleteBuzzWeft";

interface Props {
  id: string,
  currentUserId: string,
  parentId: string | null,
  content: string,
  author: {
    name: string;
    image: string;
    id: string;
  },
  community: {
    id: string;
    name: string;
    image: string;
  } | null;
  createdAt: string;
  comments: {
    author: {
      image: string;
    }
  }[]
  isComment?: boolean;
}

const BuzzWeftCard = ({ id, currentUserId, parentId, content, author, community, createdAt, comments, isComment }: Props) => {
  const [ randomLikes, setRandomLikes] = useState(0);

  useEffect(() => {
    setRandomLikes(Math.floor(Math.random() * 1000));
  }, []);

  return (
    <article className={`flex w-full flex-col rounded-xl ${isComment ? 'px-0 xs:px-7' : 'bg-dark-2 p-7'}`}>

      <div className="flex items-start justify-between">
        <div className="flex w-full flex-1 flex-row gap-4">
          <div className="flex flex-col items-center">
           
            <div className="buzz-card_bar" />
          </div>
          <div className="flex w-full flex-col">
            <p className="mt-2 text-small-regular text-light-1">{content}</p>
            <div className={`${isComment && 'mb-10'} mt-5 flex flex-col gap-3`}>
              <div className="flex gap-3.5">
                <Link href={`/`}>
                  <Image src='/assets/heart-gray.svg' alt="heart" width={24} height={24} className="cursor-pointer object-contain" />
                </Link>
                {/* <div className=""> */}
                  {/* <Link href={`/buzz/${id}`}> */}
                    <Image src='/assets/reply.svg' alt="reply" width={24} height={24} className="cursor-pointer object-contain" />
                    <p className=" text-x-small-semibold">{randomLikes}</p>
                  {/* </Link> */}
                {/* </div> */}
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>

      </div>
    </article>
  )
}

export default BuzzWeftCard
```